# A time loop manga or manhwa where mc is an office worker and the world starts to change and when he goes out he finds a Minotaur and dies

Tags: story-identification, novel, manga

It is a black and white manga or manhwa it wasn't coloured.

The main character (MC) is working in his office and talks to a girl and some other people. The world starts to change he then goes outside and finds a minotaur on his way home and dies then starts the day again with a status window. He goes to another place and finds a goblin group in a mall and kills them all. He levels up then gets strong enough to fight the minotaur but still dies again and again until he can kill the minotaur and protect the girl he likes.

After he kills the minotaur he passes out and finds himself in a hospital with the girl beside him. Two soldiers enter, one of them doesn't believe he killed the minotaur and tries to check MC's strength with a handshake. MC shows him who is boss and then the hospital is attacked by monsters. The MC goes to fight them and the girl goes with him.

The girl dies then the loop begins again but now the girl remembers everything and goes into a shock because she was ripped apart by monsters then after couple more time loops she recovers. (After this I don't remember)

Answer (score 2):

This is *[Only I Know the World Is Ending And Getting Killed by Rampaging Beasts Only Makes Me Stronger](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/only-i-know-the-world-is-ending-and-getting-killed-by-rampaging-beasts-only-makes-me-stronger)*.

> Akira Ichijo is your average, run-of-the-mill businessman. One day, on his way home from work, **he is suddenly attacked by a Minotaur and killed on the spot**. But in the blink of an eye...he wakes up back at the office! When monsters invade into the real world, a cruel reality sets in as the world as we know it plummets into destruction and death. But with the unique skill, "Resurrection," Akira can come back to life every time he dies, all the while inheriting the same levels and skills from his last run at life! With unlimited chances to correct his past mistakes, it's up to Akira to utilize the skill he's given and survive this terrifying world with his childhood friend, Nao Nanase.

The synopsis covers the minotaur encounter and coming back from the dead. The protagonist is a regular office worker that suddenly encounters a minotaur, which promptly kills him. He comes back to life and thinks this was just an awful dream, except the monster invasion still happens.

[image: The minotaur confronting the protagonist]

He fights a goblin and manages to kill it, but dies again in the process. This still gives him a level up from the kill, plus a bonus achievement for his first kill - he continually uses these boosts to get stronger.

This includes fighting a huge horde of goblins within a shop.

[image: Running from goblins within a shop]

There is a female childhood friend/coworker character that he actively tries to save; I can't confirm that she starts remembering the loops, but it seems plausible.

Comment: Thank you very much it was living in my head rent free because the last chapter I read was a cliff hanger 

Comment: @GHOSTRL You're welcome. If this is the correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).